# Where to set com.apple.application-identifier entitlement for background URLSession?

Tags: nsurlsession

I am receiving a warning in my macOS app during compilation:
`Background URLSession adopters are required to have the com.apple.application-identifier entitlement.`

J.

I am utilizing NSURLSession, but I am unable to locate where to specify this entitlement in order to resolve the warning. I initilize the NSURLSessionConfiguration  as `[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier: @"com.mycompany.myappname.analytics"]`

Comment: Normally, you shouldn't have to provide that manually at all, and if you have done so, the usual fix is to delete it: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1710/_index.html

Comment: If that doesn't help, maybe your bundle ID is invalid?

Comment: Hi, thank you, but none of this is applicable. I do not have an "Entitlements.plist" file in my project, and I do not use any entitlements. The Bundle ID is correct; I have not changed it for a couple of years. This problem appeared with Sonoma/Xcode15.

Comment: The app identifier entitlement is auto-generated by Xcode as part of signing a bundled app, independent of whether you've explicitly added other entitlements.  I'd expect to see that error if this were command-line tool, you'd need some extra codesign magic to fix it, but for a normal bundle-based app using the default build, assuming you're building for distribution, it should happen automatically.  File a feedback report using Feedback Assistant.  Also, ask on Apple's developer forums.  You might get an answer from somebody in Developer Technical Support.

Comment: Ah, I see you already posted on the forums, and Quinn is answering.  You're in good hands.  :-D